# Send Post request after download finished

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app that downloads an mp3 file from the server with URLSessionDownloadTask. But I have to notify my server with a POST request after the download is finished. But when the app in Background or iPhone is sleeping I can not send the request. How can I handle this?

Comment: With a background session?

Comment: URLSessionDownloadTask's URLSession is background session.